# Unable to point to a Fortran function that returns an array

Tags: fortran, function-pointers

I have a function that returns an array and works fine but I'm unable to point to it. I use the same pointer declaration and assignment that I successfully used with scalar result functions that take the same arguments (reals and a derived type).  The declaration is

```
  PROCEDURE( REAL(idp) ), POINTER, NOPASS :: GradSingleState
```

Which points to

```
  this % GradSingleState => GradSingleWell
```

When I try to compile with gfortran I get the error message

> ```
>        this % GradSingleState => GradSingleWell
>       1 Error: Explicit interface required for ‘’ at (1): array result
> ```

and when I compile with Intel and then run it, it crashes.

Comment: Need a minimum working example of the code; otherwise, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we know, when referencing a function which has an array result it is necessary to have an explicit interface available for the function. Your compiler is complaining about there being no explicit interface available here because with procedure pointers there is a similar requirement.

If `GradSingleWell` has an array result (requiring an explicit interface to be available when referenced) then the pointer itself must also have an explicit interface.  However, in declaring

```
PROCEDURE( REAL(idp) ), POINTER, NOPASS :: GradSingleState
```

the procedure pointer has an implicit interface (and with a scalar result rather than an array result).

To resolve this, it is required to give the pointer `GradSingleState` an explicit (and matching) interface:

```
PROCEDURE(iface), POINTER, NOPASS :: GradSingleState
```

where `iface` is an interface name. Details of how to define `iface` can be found in a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36588011/3157076).